# Web framework for Lua

Tags: lua

Looking for a **Lua port** (open source) of one of the next frameworks:

- the [Myghty framerowk](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Myghty) (python)
- or [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org) (python - successor of Myghty)
- or [HTML::Mason](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Mason) (Perl)
- or [Mason](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mason) (successor of HTML::Mason).

If nothing such exists (and probably doesn't exists, or my googling failed), looking for **any** Lua-web framework what uses *embeded Lua in the web-pages* (like php) but with the following attributes?

- component based with hierarchical page inheritance
- HTML templates (with embeded Lua code) at the 1st request are compiled into pure lua code what is cached
- and on every subsequent request only are executed the compiled (cached) lua code
- and, of course - every template execution is sandboxed

And finally, in fact, I didn't found *any* **free** Lua-framework can work at least "as php". ([LSP](https://realtimelogic.com/products/lua-server-pages/) - Lua Server pages AFAIK is commercial)

Know anyone such framework?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for http://ophal.org (free software project) since it has most of the things you are asking for:

- component based
- HTML templates (with embeded Lua code)
- every template execution is sandboxed

There is stuff you want that is handled by the corresponding nginx or apache2 lua module:

- at the 1st request are compiled into pure lua code what is cached
- and on every subsequent request only are executed the compiled (cached) lua code

Other stuff is still work in progress:

- hierarchical page inheritance